Update Discord Bot Code Without Losing Embed Interactions
I'm making a discord bot using python, but whenever my bot posts an embed with interactable buttons, and then I rerun or deploy a new update of the bot's code, when I try to interact with that button, interaction fails. Is there anyway to keep the embed interactable even after rerunning the code?
Here is an example code:
menu = View()
open_button = Button(
    label=os.getenv("CLOSE_TICKET_COMMAND_OPEN_TICKET"),
    style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary
)
open_button.callback = self.open_ticket_callback
menu.add_item(open_button)

delete_button = Button(
    label=os.getenv("CLOSE_TICKET_COMMAND_DELETE_TICKET"),
    style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger
)
delete_button.callback = self.delete_ticket_callback
menu.add_item(delete_button)

embed = discord.Embed(
    title="",
    description=os.getenv("CLOSE_TICKET_COMMAND_CLOSED_BY").format(
    user=interaction.user.mention),
    color=discord.Color(5308575)
)
await channel.send(embed=embed, view=menu)

I've tried resending the embed every time I restart the code, but I want a more efficient solution.

The thing you are looking for is persistant views.
To make a view persistant so it works even after a restart, it needs to fulfill these 2 things:

The timeout of the View has to be set to None
Every item in the View has to have a custom_id set

You can find an example here.
What you could also do, is, adding to the bot an event called on_interaction which listens to every interaction but then check, if interaction.message is your desired message with the view and do actions then.
